# convert intent link to https url mvc C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, https

I want open intent link with browser in c# mvc
or with javascript
for examle I have intent link I want intent link open with chrome when page load

```
public ActionResult ShareVideoDetails(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.Link = "intent://open_app/#Intent;scheme=dorsabarzar;package=" + AppSettings.AndroidPackageName + ";S.doctype=FRA;S.type=3;S.data=" + id + ";S.browser_fallback_url=https://2rsa.ir/2rsa.html;end";  
            return View();
        }


<script>

    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        window.location.href = "@ViewBag.Link";
    });
</script>
```

this link start with intent couldn't open in chrome

Comment: To my knowledge there is no `intent://` protocol on Android. Some people use it within WebViews and then implement a custom URL handler to handle `intent://` URLs and translate them to an Intent but in regular web browser this does not work to my knowledge. From within a web site you can only open apps that have registered to regular http[s] links (or whatever scheme the app has registered).